# c# wcf restful self hosted service closes connection / fails after too many requests

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, configuration

I have a self hosted WCF service, that should enable recording of some data that clients send.
(In my case, machines shall report done actions, that the service logs into one xml file for each machine, which is on the file system of the service host.)
For the file access there are global mutexes for each file.
The report method receives a stream, and processes that data until the file writing operations are done.

The problem is, that when I simulate the dataset reporting (1000-2000 reports, each client reports one dataset each 50-100ms, which is not a huge frequency I think) on multiple clients,
my wcf service connection sometimes seems to close (http response 400).

Furthermore the service throws Exceptions

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' in System.ServiceModel.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.HttpListenerException' in System.dll
```

and on the client side some Tasks (one task for each request) are getting canceled

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskcanceledException...
```

Firstly I thought that the Problem is in the point of file accessing, but now
I think that the problem should be in the WCF Service configuration.
Because I removed the Methods processing (just return true), started 5 clients to 5000 requests at 50ms request frequency and the problem occured.

Here's my Service Configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1"/>
    </startup>
    <!-- Webservice Configuration -->
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="Program.ServiceBehavior"
                             name="Program.HttpService.HttpService">
                <endpoint address=""
                                    binding="webHttpBinding"
                                    bindingConfiguration="RestBinding"
                                    contract="Program.HttpService.IFbmHttpService"
                                    behaviorConfiguration="web">
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex"
                                    binding="mexHttpBinding"
                                    contract="IMetadataExchange"
                                    name="MetadataEndpoint"/>
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="Program.ServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
                    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="web">
                    <webHttp/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
            <webHttpBinding>
                <binding name="RestBinding"
                                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                                 maxBufferSize="2147483647">
                    <!--<readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" />-->
                    <security mode="None">
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2000000"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.net>
        <connectionManagement>
            <add address="*" maxconnection="100"/>
        </connectionManagement>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Try adding maxconcurrent calls, have a look at https://codewala.net/2014/10/14/simple-steps-scale-up-wcf-drastically/

Comment: I already "landed" there and I already tried to increase these settings with maxConcurrentCalls – 144
maxConcurrentSessions – 800
maxConcurrentInstances –  944, which sounds like a bit too hughe for a simple host computer (one requirement is that the host computer is a common desktop pc. at leat for early development stages).

Comment: The client side exceptions might be caused by timeouts:
https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/233134-taskcanceledexception-on-timeout-on-httpclient/
but increasing the timeouts seems not to be the right workaround for me.
However, I tried and increased the timeouts from default (00:01:00) to 00:10:00 as in the example of https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-timeout-values-on-a-binding
It didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Could it be a run condition issue (that should actually be prevented by using a mutex for each file)?
The test client is on my machine as my running service. So lots of connections and threads arise in this "stress test".
My Service seems to work fine with realistic conditions.